# How to checkin IFC file to BIMserver using java for Users

Tags: java, ifc, bim

The follow code is part of a Java client for the [Opensource BIMserver](https://github.com/opensourcebim/bimserver).

```
JsonBimServerClientFactory factory = new JsonBimServerClientFactory("");
BimServerClient client = factory.create(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationInfo("exple@dd.com", "poiuy"));
String randomName = "yu" + new Random().nextLong();

// Create a new project with a random name
SProject project = client.getServiceInterface().addProject(randomName, "ifc2x3tc1");
long poid = project.getOid();
String comment = "";

// This method is an easy way to find a compatible deserializer for the combination of
// the "ifc" file extension and this project. You can also get a specific deserializer
// if you want to.
SDeserializerPluginConfiguration deserializer = client.getServiceInterface().getSuggestedDeserializerForExtension("ifc", poid);

// Make sure you change this to a path to a local IFC file
String absolutePathOfFile = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "resources/images/IFC/stickfile.ifc";

java.nio.file.Path demoIfcFile = Paths.get(absolutePathOfFile);
// Here we actually checkin the IFC file.
```

Above code works fine for checkin of IFC file if a user is of type "Administrator" but does not working for a user of type "User". So how to checkin an IFC file for a user without admin privilege?

Comment: Does the user has appropriate file permissions?

Comment: if user is of type "User" then he can not upload only if User is Administrator then he has a permission to upload

Comment: Can you add the exception message to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Users of type "User" can not create projects. If you create a project with a user of type "Admin", you have to grant the "User" type user permissions on this project using

```
client.getServiceInterface().addUserToProject(userOid, projectOid)
```

The code is likely to fail already at the `addProject` call. Please confirm with the stacktrace and the error message returned from the service call.